# Prove the given property of the Fibonacci numbers directly from the definition.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

$$
[F(n + 1)]^2 = [F(n)]^2 + F(n − 1)F(n + 2) 
\text{ for } n \geq 2
$$

I started by breaking up the leftmost term into:
$$
    F[n+1] \cdot F[n+1]
$$

I then used the Fibonacci relation to break them into:
$$
    [F(n) + F(n-1)][F(n) + F(n-1)]
$$
I multiplied them together to give myself:
$$
    [F(n)]^2 + 2[F(n-1)F(n)] + [F(n-1)]^2
$$
Though I am stuck after this part. If anyone can offer me insight as to whether I am heading in the right direction, or point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: you forgot a $2$ multiplying $F(n-1)F(n)$.

Comment: The hint given the correction is to gather $F(n-1)$ from the last two terms

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: $2F(n-1)F(n) + F(n-1)^2 =F(n-1)(2F(n)+F(n-1))$ and so...

Comment: Hint: $[F(n + 1)]^2 - [F(n)]^2 =(F(n + 1) - F(n)) (F(n + 1)+F(n))$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the largest index that appears in the identity is $n+2$, so you want to apply the recurrence there:
$$
F(n+2) = F(n+1) + F(n).
$$
Can you take it from there?